# What adapters are available for a connecting a secondary SSD to the Superdrive's SATA cable?

Tags: imac, ssd, optical-drive, sata

I have a 2011 iMac. I plan to replace the SuperDrive with an SSD drive. I've noticed on various images of, e.g., on ifixit, that the SATA cable that plugs into the Superdrive looks different to the female SATA connector on the SSD drive I have ordered (and Intel 510).

Does anyone know what (if any) adapters I will need to plug the SSD drive into the Superdrive's SATA/power connectors.

For clarity - I'm completely removing the Superdrive from the machine; I don't plan on sharing anything between the SSD/Superdrive. The SSD will have the sole use of whatever cable is is currently plugging into the Superdrive.

Comment: Are you aware that your task will require lots of tweaking? Opening up an iMac is quite something. Also you will void your warranty.

Comment: I'm aware of the task yes. It's no big deal (I've completed much more challenging upgrades in the past). I'm in the UK and the Sales of Goods overrides any manufacturer's warranty. . . If there was another problem with my iMac, not caused by my meddling, the machine would still be covered under that act.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Superdrive uses a slimline 13 pin SATA connection. The cable left after the removal of the Superdrive is female.

Therefore, in order to fit a 2.5" SSD drive to the SATA Superdrive cable you need to acquire a 13 pin slimline SATA male to 22 pin SATA female adapter, which can be acquired on eBay and various other places.

Hope this helps others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Should be similar to the one I got for my MacBookPro, actually here is one especially for iMacs:
[OWC Data Doubler](http://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/DDMMCL0GB/)

I got another one from ebay for ~20 $ - does not fit perfectly, but is good enough for me. Up to you which way you go.

MacBookPro installation was not too difficult, don't know about difficulty for iMacs.